# Error when applying box-shadow style in CSS - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to use the following box-shadow effect:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 rgb(231 238 242 / 8%);
```

It works well when directly applied to the element. But when placed in the .css file, it returns the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 3) for `rgb'
```

May I know what is the root cause please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use:

`box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 rgb(231 238 242/8%);`

The whitespace is problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your **`box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 rgb(231 238 242 / 8%);`** the error in your coloring check your number of arugments for proper color:

You can try this:
**`box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 rgb(231 238 242)`**